# styling is not being added to my angular html inspite using ng style

Tags: css, angular

```css
.header1 {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 500px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<main class="four-card-body">
  <div class="header1" [ngStyle]="{'text-align': 'center !important;'}">
    <h1> Reliable, efficient delivery</h1>
    <h1>
      Powered by Technology
    </h1>
    <div class="headerTitle">
      <p>
        Our Artificial Intelligence powered tools use millions of project data points to ensure that your project is successful
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

the above code runs fine normally but in the angular component the styling is not getting linked
though main class four card body is getting style but div is not getting styled

Comment: why you want to use ngStyle where you can achieve this by regular inline style attribute..

Comment: even if i remove ngStyle and link with component.css
the style for four-card-body is working but not working for the inner div tag
whatever i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not understand `!important` hence does not convert it to `style="text-align: center"`.

Remove the `!important` and you will see the inline style added to div with class `.header1`. However, it will apply the alignment style from `.header1` class because of the `!important`.

Comment: no it does not do any good i had tried it earlier
also the problem is i think the css is not getting linked header1 class of div
in the component.css